# spring2.5 javamailsender locked in javax.mail.service.connect

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, email

I used spring 2.5 JavaMailSenderImpl to send mails. When I sent more than 10,000 mails, my program got blocked. This was the thread information showed by jstack:

```
"pool-4-thread-6" prio=10 tid=0x000000001b94d800 nid=0x44fb runnable    [0x0000000041901000] 
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE 
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) 
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150) 
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121) 
        at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:97) 
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235) 
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254) 
        - **locked** <0x00000000e6e2d170> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream) 
        at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:75) 
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1440) 
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1260) 
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370) 
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275) 
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.ja 
va:389)  
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java 
:342) 
        at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java 
:338)
```

Perhaps this program was blocked beceuse of the mail connection，but I deployed out-time in the spring config file:

```
    <property name ="javaMailProperties"> 
                 <props> 
                 <prop key="mail.smtp.connectiontimeout">25000</prop>   
                <prop key="mail.smtp.timeout">25000</prop> 
             </props> 
</property >
```

program should throw an exception when time exceed.but it still gets blocked!!
Is anyone who knows the reasons?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it could also be because of the restriction placed by SMTP server. To prevent spamming, many SMTP servers allows a limited set of email sending within a given time range.

In this case, the flow might simply be waiting and looks blocked. Check your SMTP admin for these restrictions.